# Typescript type Never[] not assignable to object array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an object array, for example:

```
objectExample[a].push({ id: john, detail: true });
objectExample[a].push({ id: james, detail: false});

const objectExample = {
   a = [ { id: john, detail: true}, 
         { id: james, detail: false}];
   }
```

If I try this in Typescript:

```
const objectExmaple: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string | boolean}[]} = [];
```

I get this error on objectType:

```
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: { [key: string]: string | boolean; }[]; }'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'never[]'.ts(2322)
```

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectExmaple` is an object, not an array, so you need to initialize it using `{}`. Also if you want for key `a` to have an array you will need to put that it either at init or before using `push`:

```
const objectExmaple: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string | boolean }[] } = {
  a: []
};

objectExmaple['a'].push({ id: 'john', detail: true });
objectExmaple['a'].push({ id: 'james', detail: false});
```

Also the type could be written more legibly  as `Record<string, Array<Record<string, string | boolean>>>`

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=77&pln=1&pc=22#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsKBRAHgWwIYAcAbZALhgCVUQAnAEwB5pqBLMAcwBoYBBa63AJ71KoOoygt2XJqzYwAPjHggQxXGAB8WmAF4YAbwCwAKBgxcZANoBdEwF8A3CZMIUaLHiLJLAclw-rADp8AFcIAAsACn0YZloyH0QQcLAfLlpkKFxmQjIJEOQYOwBKJ2NXVAwcAmJffyDQiOjY+JhE3GxkCDSYDKycsgAzXEIIZBKy52MgA)

Comment: Is there a way to separate out the object properties? for example, `{ [key: string]: { [key: string]: string, [key: string]: boolean}[]};`?

Comment: @warrenfitzhenry You can have an explicit type if you know the properties in the object `Record<string, Array<{id: string, detail: boolean}>>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

- You can't initialize `objectExample` to `[]` if it is an object
- The type definition is complex for nothing

```
type Item = { [key: string]: string | boolean}
// Same as type Item = { [key: string]: string | boolean}

const objectExample: Record<string, Item[]> = {
   a: [ { id: 'john', detail: true}, 
         { id: 'james', detail: false}]
}

objectExample.a.push({ id: 'john', detail: true });
objectExample.a.push({ id: 'james', detail: false});
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8oG0DWEQC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1CSKaoAfKAIwHtOAbCAQ0oBfAFABjTpRJRO7AFYQxwAKIAPfgjB9CAJUWdSAEwA8jKtQA0seAky0AfCnQior-oUzoo5Q4QDkcpwAFpR+VoYQwPzkPIRkAK4QQlYurmlpGD7+choQRGFQEVExhABm-DxESbQioiKyCkpqGloQAHT8bWDxREEAFJm+UAHBoeGR0bFQCdBCAJQA3PXyiirqmnwdXT39g9m5+ePFU+WVSYtAA) is a link to a working playground